# Some of two elements in an array

Tags: python

Below is the python code:

```
def addition(list1,x):

    left  = 0

    list1 = list1.sort()
    print list1
    right  = len(list1)- 1
    while left < right:
        if list1[left] + list1[right] > x:
            right =right -1
        elif  list1[left] + list1[right] <x:
            left =left +1

        else:
            return True
    return False


data_1 = [3,4,5,2,1,10,2,5,33]
print "output"
print addition(data_1,6)
```

In the above code there is an error. Could you please help me?

Comment: Would help if you tell us what error you see

Comment: on  right  = len(list1)- 1 it is showing as len is not part of none object

Comment: replace `list1.sort()` with `sorted(list1)`

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`.

You should use `list1.sort()`, not `list1 = list1.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

`.sort` sorts in-place and returns `None`, which of course has no attributes- hence the error.

Use instead:

```
# This sorts the list in-place, so don't assign the result to a variable.
list1.sort()
```

or

```
# This function returns a new list, so you can assign it to a variable.
list1 = sorted(list1)
```